# How to transform Pandas DataFrame from columns-index shape to columns-columns shape summarizing values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transformation

I have organisations (represented by columns, 'fakulta') which cooperated (or not) on numerous projects (rows, 'ID_RIV').

Input DF:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'FEI':[1,0,0,1,0],
                   'HGF':[0,1,1,0,0],
                   'FBI':[0,1,1,1,1]},
                  index = [1,2,3,4,5])

df.index.name = 'ID_RIV'
df.columns.name = 'fakulta'

print(df)
```

```
fakulta  FEI  HGF  FBI
ID_RIV                
1          1    0    0
2          0    1    1
3          0    1    1
4          1    0    1
5          0    0    1
```

I'd like to know who cooperated with whom.

How could I transform input DF to a symmetric matrix (square DF) like this:

Desired Output:

```
     FEI HGF FBI
FEI    1   0   1
HGF    0   0   2
FBI    1   2   1
```

Comment: UMMM can you explain your output

Comment: He is computing the matches between pairs of columns in the array, and putting the single occurrences in the diagonal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a dot product and replacing the diagonal afterwards. This returns exactly the output you need.

```
import numpy as np
df_out = df.T.dot(df)


df_singles = df.loc[df.sum(axis=1)==1]     
df_singles = df_singles.T.dot(df_singles)   

df_out.values[[np.arange(df_out.shape[0])]*2] = df_singles.values[[np.arange(df_singles.shape[1])]*2]

In [273]: df_out
Out[273]: 
     FEI  HGF  FBI
FEI    1    0    1
HGF    0    0    2
FBI    1    2    1
```